# Modify parts of a matrix based on linear equation on row and column numbers

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

For example:

```
>> tmp = ones(5,5)

tmp =

     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
```

I want a command like:

```
tmp(colNum - 2*rowNum > 0) = 0
```

that modifies entries of `tmp` when the column number is more than twice the row number e.g. it should produce:

```
tmp =

     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     0
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
```

As a second example, `tmp(colNum - rowNum == 0) = 0` should set the diagonal elements of `tmp` to be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to generate a grid of 2D coordinates, then use this to impose any condition you wish.  The variant you seek outputs 2 2D matrices where the first matrix gives you the column locations and the second matrix outputs the row locations.

For example, given your situation above:

```
>> [X,Y] = meshgrid(1:5, 1:5)

X =

     1     2     3     4     5
     1     2     3     4     5
     1     2     3     4     5
     1     2     3     4     5
     1     2     3     4     5


Y =

     1     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3     3
     4     4     4     4     4
     5     5     5     5     5
```

You can see that each unique spatial location shared between `X` and `Y` give you the desired 2D location as if you were envisioning a 2D grid.

Therefore, you would do something like this for your first situation:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:5,1:5); % Generate 2D coordinates
tmp = ones(5); % Generate desired matrix
tmp(X > 2*Y) = 0; % Set desired locations to 0
```

We get:

```
>> tmp

tmp =

     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     0
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
```

Finally for your second example:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:5,1:5); % Generate 2D coordinates
tmp = ones(5); % Generate desired matrix
tmp(X == Y) = 0;  % Set desired locations to 0
```

We get:

```
>> tmp

tmp =

     0     1     1     1     1
     1     0     1     1     1
     1     1     0     1     1
     1     1     1     0     1
     1     1     1     1     0
```

Simply put, generate a grid of 2D coordinates, then use those directly to index into your desired matrix using `logical` / Boolean conditions to set the desired locations to 0.

Comment: No problem at all. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

A possibly more efficient solution is to use `bsxfun` like so

```
nRows = 5;
nCols = 5;
bsxfun(@(col,row)~(col - 2*row > 0), 1:nCols, (1:nRows)')
```

You can generalize this to just accept a function so it becomes

```
bsxfun(@(col,row)~f(col,row), 1:nCols, (1:nRows)')
```

And now just replace `f` with exactly the way you specify the equation in your question i.e.

```
f = @(colNum, rowNum)(colNum - 2*rowNum > 0)
```

or

```
f = @(colNum, rowNum)(colNum - rowNum == 0)
```

of course it might make more sense to specify your function to accept `(row,col)` instead of `(col,row)` as that's how MATLAB indexes

Comment: You may want to check your variable names in your `bsxfun` calls....  Specifically towards the end of each statement.